# svn cleaup results svn: E155016: The working copy database at '/..../..../../' is corrupt

Tags: svn

The subversion repository is corrupted and while trying to run `svn clean up` the below error message is shown.

`svn: E155016: The working copy database at '/..../..../../' is corrupt`

Please advice what can be done?

Version:
svn, version 1.8.15 (r1718365)
compiled Jul 28 2017, 13:10:06 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1):

The working copy is corrupted, but you can checkout a new one. Just do not remove the corrupted one if it contains modified files. You may want to copy them to the new working copy.

> Version: svn, version 1.8.15 (r1718365) compiled Jul 28 2017, 13:10:06
>   on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Current Subversion client version is 1.13.x! Upgrade your Subversion client.